# having trouble inserting values into table with syntax error

Tags: java, sql, insert, syntax-error

Everytime at around "composedLine = String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s", composedLine,
values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);"
it produces "INSERT INTO airport VALUES (, ABR, Aberdeen Regional Airport, Aberdeen"

instead of "INSERT INTO airport VALUES (ABR, Aberdeen Regional Airport, Aberdeen"

which causes a syntax error when I use executeupdate due to the "," before the ABR.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UsaDelayFlight {
    


        
    

    public static Connection connectToDatabase(String user, String password, String database) {
            System.out.println("------ Testing PostgreSQL JDBC Connection ------");
            Connection connection = null;
            try {
                String protocol = "jdbc:postgresql://";
                String dbName = "";
                String fullURL = protocol + database + dbName + user;
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(fullURL, user, password);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                String errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                if (errorMsg.contains("authentication failed")) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: \tDatabase password is incorrect. Have you changed the password string above?");
                    System.out.println("\n\tMake sure you are NOT using your university password.\n"
                            + "\tYou need to use the password that was emailed to you!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection failed! Check output console.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return connection;
        }
        
        public static void dropTable(Connection connection, String table) throws SQLException  {
            Statement st = null;
            try {
            st = connection.createStatement();
            boolean result = st.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            st.close();
        }
        
        public static void createTable(Connection connection, String tableDescription) throws SQLException  {
            Statement st = null;
            try {
            st = connection.createStatement();
            boolean result = st.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableDescription);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            st.close();
        }
        
        public static ResultSet executeQuery(Connection connection, String query) {
             System.out.println("DEBUG: Executing query...");
             try {
             Statement st = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
             return rs;
             } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return null;
             }
             }
        
        public static int insertIntoTableFromFile(Connection connection, String table, 
                String filename) {
            int numRows = 0;
            String currentLine = null;
            try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            // Read in each line of the file until we reach the end.
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = currentLine.split(",");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
            String composedLine = "INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES (";
            //String r = String.format("formatted values are %s", composedLine);
            composedLine = String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s", composedLine,
                     values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
            System.out.println(composedLine);
             //. . .
            // Finally, execute the entire composed line.
            numRows = st.executeUpdate(composedLine);
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return numRows;
        }
        
        
            
            // NOTE: You will need to change some variables from START to END.
                public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {
                    // START
                    // Enter your username.
                    String user = "";
                    // Enter your database password, NOT your university password.
                    String password = "";
                    
                    /** IMPORTANT: If you are using NoMachine, you can leave this as it is.
                     * 
                     *  Otherwise, if you are using your OWN COMPUTER with TUNNELLING:
                     *      1) Delete the original database string and 
                     *      2) Remove the '//' in front of the second database string.
                     */
                    String database = "";
                    //String database = "";
                    // END
                    
                    Connection connection = connectToDatabase(user, password, database);
                    if (connection != null) {
                        System.out.println("SUCCESS: You made it!"
                                + "\n\t You can now take control of your database!\n");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: \tFailed to make connection!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    // Now we're ready to use the DB. You may add your code below this line.
                    createTable(connection, "delayedFlights (ID_of_Delayed_Flight varchar(15) not null, Month varchar(10), "
                            + "DayofMonth int, DayofWeek int, DepTime timestamp, ScheduledDepTime timestamp, ArrTime int,"
                            + "ScheduledArrTime timestamp, UniqueCarrier varchar(15) not null, FlightNum int, ActualFlightTime timestamp,"
                            + "scheduledFlightTime timestamp, AirTime timestamp, ArrDelay timestamp, DepDelay timestamp, Orig varchar(15),"
                            + "Dest varchar(15), Distance int, primary key (ID_of_Delayed_Flight), unique (UniqueCarrier));");
                    
                    createTable(connection, "airport (airportCode varchar(15) not null, "
                            + "airportName varchar(15), City varchar(15), State varchar(15), primary key (airportCode));");
                    
                    insertIntoTableFromFile(connection, "airport", "airport");
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM delayedFlights;";
                     ResultSet rs = executeQuery(connection, query);
                     try {
                     while (rs.next()) {
                     System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
                     }
                     } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     rs.close();
                }
                
    
    }
```

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: Or perhaps PostgeSQL (based on the lines `String protocol = "jdbc:postgresql://";` and `------ Testing PostgreSQL JDBC Connection ------`... Tag properly, don't just spam them

Comment: `boolean result = st.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table);` also looks dangerously open to injection attacks.

Comment: Just a note. Though it perfectly doable, real world apps rarely create and drop tables on the fly. Data is too valuable to lose it by a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code is a security vulnerability**. Specifically, SQL injection. This is not how you do it.

The correct way also solves your problem in passing. Thus, solution: Do it the correct way, solves all your problems.

Correct way:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, values[0]);
ps.setString(2, values[1]);
ps.setString(3, values[2]);
ps.setString(4, values[3]);
ps.executeUpdate();
```